# Show that $\mathsf P\left[\bigcap_iA_i\right]\ge\sum_i\mathsf P(A_i)-(n-1)$

Tags: probability

> Let $A_1, A_2, \dots$ be events. Show that for all $n\ge1$
>   $$\mathsf P\left[\bigcap_iA_i\right]\ge\sum_i\mathsf P(A_i)-(n-1)$$

I am able to prove this for $n=2$ but I need to prove it for all $n$. When $n=2$ there's events A and B with
$$\mathsf P(A\cap B)\ge\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B)-(2-1)$$

which may be seen from the following relations:
$$\mathsf P(A\cup B)=\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B)-\mathsf P(A\cap B)$$
$$\mathsf P(A\cap B)=\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B)-\mathsf P(A\cup B)$$
$$P(A\cup B)≤1$$

To prove for all $n$ I think I need to use inclusion–exclusion, but where does the $n-1$ come from?

Comment: Maybe it should read $P(A\cup B)≤ 1$?

Comment: you are correct. sorry for the mixup.

Comment: No problem.  Have you tried induction?  Assuming it is true for $\{A_1,\cdots, A_{n-1}\}$ let $A=\bigcap_{i=1}^{n-1}A_i$ and let $B=A_n$ and use your two state argument.

Comment: This is the general Bonferroni's inequality. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2102774/show-pa-cap-b-geq-papb-1/2103079#2103079).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After rearranging a lot of terms, the inequality you want becomes
$$
\sum_i(1-P(A_i))\geq1-P(\bigcap_iA_i).
$$
Now use that, for any event $X$, $1-P(X)=PX^c)$ (where the superscript $c$ means complement) and that $(\bigcap_iA_i)^c =\bigcup_i({A_i}^c)$.